# Should I ever set the ID of a fragment root view?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm hitting an issue where the root ID of a fragment is being changed when it's expanded by an activity. I'm able to work around it, but I'm trying to figure out if putting an ID on a root view should always be avoided so that it doesn't get renamed in the situation where a user attaches it to an activity via XML.

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.fragmenttest.MainActivityFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and this is my fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mylayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, if I want to refer to the RelativeLayout during my fragment's onCreateView, I can call findViewById(R.id.mylayout) and it works. However, if I call it later, I can't use

```
rl = getView().findViewById(R.id.mylayout);
```

because the root view's ID has changed to R.id.fragment (and I could use that to get the RelativeLayout).

So I'm wondering if I should ever be setting the ID of the fragment's root view on the off chance the next developer is going to use it directly in XML.

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

            MainActivityFragment fragment = (MainActivityFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
            fragment.doIdTest();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And MainActivityFragment:

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

    public void doIdTest() {
        View rl = getView().findViewById(R.id.mylayout);

        if (rl == null) {
            Log.wtf("Ack!", "Can't find the RelativeLayout!");
        }

        rl = getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment);

        if (rl != null && rl instanceof RelativeLayout) {
            Log.wtf("Ack!", "ID of the relative layout is fragment!");
        }
    }
}
```

A full project demonstrating the issue can be seen here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/08xu4bxi84rsms3/FragmentTest.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: I think that it should work. Why are you arguing that the id will change? You should just be sure that you call it after the `onCreateView()`, for example inside the `onViewCreated()`.

Comment: @Joseph82 Because the ID does change.  If from MainActivity, I call MyFragment.doIt() , I can't find the relativeLayout using the R.id.mylayout.  The new ID is R.id.fragment, which is the ID given to the fragment in the activity XML.

Comment: But, the Fragment should act over its layout. And inside the Fragment you can always 'call getView().findViewById(R.id.mylayout)' without worrying about the fragment id.

Comment: No, no I can't. I've tested this. it actually fails. This is not theoretical.

Comment: When you call it? from where?

Comment: `getView` returns the rootview of the `Fragment` and doesn't change its id if it has one. Whatever you're seeing of weird behaviour you have to document with a code example, which you're not with the code above. ;-) And besides you don't need an id to use `getView`.

Comment: I'm guessing the ID is actually changed after the Fragment is expanded, but some point along the process of attaching it to the Activity.

Full example can be seen here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/08xu4bxi84rsms3/FragmentTest.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: Yeah, I tried your code out - the `FragmentManager` is actually changing the `Id`... check my "answer" below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried your code, and I'm afraid I'm seeing the same things as you are - the `Id` of the rootview which is the `RelativeLayout` is actually changing from `R.id.myLayout` to `R.id.fragment`. :O

I did a little digging and found that inside `Activity#setContentView` it actually calls the `FragmentManager` which in return will call all `Fragment`s added to the `Activity`. Then `FragmentManager#onCreateView` is being called when `Fragment#onCreateView` is called.

When `Fragment#onCreateView` is called then the rootview of the `Fragment` is still `R.id.myLayout`, but after the `FragmentManager#onCreateView` has been called, for some reason this method changes the `Id` of the `mView` and `mInnerView` of the `Fragment` in this part of the code:

```
if (id != 0) {
    fragment.mView.setId(id);
}
```

At this point `fragment.mView` already have an `Id` set - the `R.id.myLayout`.

There is no explanation in the code for why this happens and why it's needed, but fact is that it happens.

For reference here's a [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/28VQGJxE) of the `FragmentManager#onCreateView` method.

**Now for what I would do**, is to forget about the `Id` `R.id.myLayout` of your `RelativeLayout`.

You will always be able to get the `RelativeLayout` by doing like this from the `Activity` for instance:

```
MainActivityFragment fragment = (MainActivityFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
RelativeLayout rootView = (RelativeLayout) fragment.getView();
```

The `getView` will always return the rootview and it can be cast to the `RelativeLayout`. It's not pretty, but I think that's how it should work.

If you want to get the `RelativeLayout` from within the `Fragment`, just call `getView` directly and cast it a `RelativeLayout` or make a global variable for the rootview inside the `Fragment` - that's at least what we do in our code at my work :-)

Also, if you remove the `Id` of the `Fragment` inside the `activity_main.xml` the `FragmentManager#onCreateView` will still overwrite the current `Id` of your `RelativeLayout` and you won't be able to use `View#findViewById` still.

As to why Google did this overwriting the `Id` I can't answer, but then again the whole `Fragment` system is a bit shaky in my opinion.

I hope this sheds some light on what is actually happening at least :-)

Comment: I know I can just grab the rootView in this simplified scenario, but I can see scenarios where the fragment may use different layouts depending on admin/non-admin.

Thanks for your help.  I've submitted an Android bug report with the info you found. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=172173

Comment: No problem - though I can't really come up with a scenario where I would have to use `findViewById` instead of a reference directly to a view? :-)
Not sure if this is a bug in the framework, but let's see what Google has to say about it :-)

Comment: Phone/tablet layouts could be one scenario.  Or if you're logged in as an admin, your listview may be a child, but if you're a user, then it's the root.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set an ID for the RelativeLayout of your Fragment.

```
public final class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private TextView mTextView;
    private RelativeLayout mRoot;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
        final LayoutInflater inflater,
        final ViewGroup container,
        final Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        mRoot     = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_main, container);
        mTextView = (TextView) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.text);
        return mRoot;
    }
}
```

The ID of the Fragment can be used to get the Fragment through a FragmentManager.

```
final FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); // getSupportFragmentManager()
final MainFragment f     = (MainFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
```

Comment: I know I don't need to, but is it an error to ever set it?  It seems bad to have the Fragment have different ID's if it was created dynamically vs. an inline XML declaration.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. I never set the ID of a root layout (doing android development since years). Fragments can be referenced by ID or Tag. If you want to change a Fragment during runtime you have to setup a fragment container, like shown here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

Comment: I'm looking at code where the root ID was set, and it causes it to fail if (and only if) the fragment is used by an Activity declaring it directly in XML with an ID there.

If Android is going to change the ID on me, perhaps ID'ing the root view shouldn't be allowed.  Or the Fragment ID shouldn't overwrite the Root View ID.